# Handler not working for 60 seconds delay?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-handler

I'm running a Handler to show some notifications in the background. While testing, when I set the delay limit to 5 seconds it works perfectly. But whenever I set it to 60 seconds or more it doesn't work. Why is that?

```
    int delay = 1000 * 60;
    HandlerThread hThread = new HandlerThread("HandlerThread");
    hThread.start();
    Handler handler = new Handler(hThread.getLooper());

    Runnable task = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            Intent launchIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AndroidLauncher.class);
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, launchIntent, 0);

            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(AndroidLauncher.this);
            //Set notification information
            builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setTicker("Hi!")
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                    .setContentTitle(mytitle)
                    .setContentText(mytext)
                    .setContentIntent(contentIntent);

            NotificationCompat.InboxStyle style = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle(builder);
            style.setSummaryText("4 Task");
            style.addLine("Two");
            style.addLine("Three");
            style.addLine("Four");
            style.addLine("Five");

            Notification note = style.build();
            manager.notify(50, note);
        }
    };

    handler.postDelayed(task, delay);
```

Comment: It's  not related to 60 second or so post your Handler code or some logs.

Comment: you tagged with `android-studio` for what reason really?

Comment: Because I'm working with android studio.

Answer (score 1):

**Import** `import android.os.Handler;`

and use following piece of code :

```
  new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //do your work here after 60 second
                }
            },60000);
```

There is good tutorial about `Handler`, `HandlerThread`, `Looper` [here](https://blog.nikitaog.me/2014/10/11/android-looper-handler-handlerthread-i/).